# How to create (or insert into MySQL) single order ID from cart function using foreach

Tags: php, mysql, foreach, e-commerce, cart

I am trying to develop a store and am stuck due to my poor knowledge in PHP, I read online and try to implement with minimal understanding.

When I insert the cart items into MySQL so that I can generate an order number, each insert creates multiple ids by way of auto increment. What I want is one ID for all the products passed in that query so that I can take it to checkout page where I take user details. I have a `foreach` loop, which helps me display products perfectly, but when I try using insert, it creates separate ids.

What I need is single order ID for each query, where temporary cart items can be passed onto checkout page and into MySQL

Following is my code:

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once("inc/connect.php");


?>


     <?php
if(isset($_SESSION["cart_item"])){
    $item_total = 0;
?>  

<?php


    $data = ''; 
 foreach ($_SESSION["cart_item"] as $item){


                $product_id = $item["id"];
                $quantity_per_product = $item["quantity"];
$data .= "(NULL, '$product_id', '$quantity_per_product', NULL),"; 

} 
$data = rtrim($data, ','); 
$ad="INSERT INTO `orders`(`order_id` ,`product_id` ,`quantity_per_product` ,`modified`)
VALUES $data;";


$q2 = mysqli_query($connection, $ad);

if (!$q2)
  {
  echo ('Q2 failed: ' . mysql_error());
  }
 else {echo 'success Q2';

echo "query: "; print_r($ad);}




$order_id=mysqli_insert_id($connection);   
echo "<script language='javascript'>
window.location = 'checkout.php?checkout=$order_id';
</script>";

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

MySQL is behaving correctly here - you want each of these items to have a separately generated primary key. However, I think the problem is your database design.

You're inserting shopping cart items into an `order` table, but shopping cart items are not orders. They are order items.

Thus, you need another table. I would rename your current table `order` to `order_item`, and continue using that structure as you do now. However, prior to this, create a single row in an `order` table, which will auto-generate a primary key for your whole order.

Finally, when you insert into `order_item`, you can insert the primary key `order.id` as a foreign key, to link items to the order they are part of. This models the real-world situation of one order having zero to many order items, and one order item having exactly one order.

---

Aside: your `INSERT` query is being built using concatenation, which may expose you to SQL injection vulnerabilities. Use parameter binding instead. Luckily, you are using the MySQLi database connector, which supports [input parameter binding](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) out of the box.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, am trying to absorb as much as I can and try to figure a way out. I understood what you explained, but I dont really have an idea about the HOW factor, how will the php code change.

Comment: @KedarPatwa: break the problem down into pieces - some of this is in my answer already. Rename your `order` table to `order_item`, then check it still works as it does now. Then create a new `order` table, and check that code works. Then do an insert into that when you checkout (regardless of the number of items in your basket). Obtain the PK and insert/update that in all of your `order_item` rows in this basket. One step at a time `:-)`.